# Redirect to Login Page when Authentication mode set to Windows in MVC

Tags: windows, asp.net-mvc-4, windows-authentication

I have a MVC application where authentication mode set to "Windows". So basically,
Anonymous Authentication is Enabled and Windows Authentication is Enabled too. Now the requirement is something like this:

1. When any user tries to access application and if he is in domain, he should be authenticated automatically to the application and authorized to access resources as per the rights assigned to him.
2. When any user tries to access application from outside the domain, he should be redirected to custom login page where he can enter username and password to authenticate himself and authorized to access resources as per the rights assigned to him.

I am able to do this with "Forms" authentication but I want to do it by setting it to Windows authentication so that it authenticates automatically for Windows AD users when in domain.

Is there any solution by adding handler or anything else?

Comment: You're looking for mixed mode. Good luck as its generally tricky since iis doesn't like running both modes at once. I believe there is an owin middleware someone wrote out there, but I didn't find it to be as graceful as i had hoped.

Comment: Hey Brad, I know you are right. I am presently looking at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972958.aspx. Let's see if I get a solution.